# Вылетает часть шаблона из редактора tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Когда закидываю готовый html шаблон со всей структурой в tinymce, иногда случается такая вещь : часть шаблона просто тупо вылетает за пределы,а другая остается в редакторе.Наглядная картинка - [image]

Как это решить?

Comment: а как вы закидываете? Выглядит как будто у вас в шаблоне есть </textarea> и все что идет после попадает к вам на страницу.. тут надо колдовать с htmlspecialchars / escape

Comment: @Darth В том-то и дело что закидываю через PHP.Но страница специально закидывается от html до закрывающего.

Comment: ну вот, я так и подумал. вам надо содержимое textarea с tinymce экранировать. он не виноват. у вас там банально закрывающий тег в вашем шаблоне

Comment: @Darth Можно чтобы редактор  исправлял шаблон на лету? Так как шаблонов много проходит через него...

Comment: в него часть вашего шаблона банально не попадает. он её не видит. он видит все, что лежит внутри его textarea, а так как в вашем шаблоне тоже есть такие теги, выходит так что шаблон читается редактором от открытия собственного тега до закрытия этого тега в шаблоне. а все дальнейшее воспринимается браузером как продолжение страницы

Comment: `<meta charset='utf8'/>
Страница
Страница
<textarea>
 Шаблон
 <br/>
 Шаблон
 <textarea>
  textarea внутри шаблона
 </textarea>
 Шаблон выпал в страницу!
</textarea>
Страница
Страница
` вот, наглядно что у вас происходит. сохраните это в html файл и откройте в браузере для просветеления

Comment: вам нужно заэкранировать с помощью php html теги в шаблоне, перед тем как вы его вставляете в textarea для редактирования

Comment: и для начала отрубите tinymce, он вас только путает. когда разберетесь с шаблоном - включите обратно